# FlatList in React Native does not render when only one item

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I'm trying to render item using FlatList in React Native project. So my problem is when I render 2 items I can see the result but when there is only on item in my data array they is no result on my screen any idea why this is happening?

```
 const data = this.getListPrise()

 <View>
    <View style={styles.allPAge} >
       <View style={styles.centerText}>
          <Text style={styles.text}>Voici vos differentes capture </Text>
        </View>
        <View  style={{flex: 1}}>
        <FlatList
          data={data}
          renderItem={({ item }) =>
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.container}  onPress={() => this.modifCapture(item)}>
              <Image style={styles.mark} source={avatar}></Image>
              <View style={styles.displayUnder}  >
                <Text style={styles.textCapture}><Text style={styles.textCaptureTitle}>Espèce </Text>: {item.espece}</Text>
                <Text style={styles.textCapture}><Text style={styles.textCaptureTitle}>Date </Text>:
                      {moment(item.date).format(" D MMMM  YYYY, h:mm:ss")}</Text>
                <Text style={styles.textCapture}><Text style={styles.textCaptureTitle}>Poids </Text> : {item.poids} kg</Text>
              </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>  
          }
          style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'column', padding: 1 }}
        />
        </View>
         <ActionButton buttonColor="rgba(231,76,60,1)" onPress={() => this.Addfish()}></ActionButton>
       <View>

    </View>
      </View>

    </View>
```

Comment: Have you tried to use console.log to inspect the contents of data when you think there is only a single item, just to confirm there really is one item as opposed to none?